# How to order a queryset by related objects count?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My `models.py` is currently set up as follows:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic

class Comic(models.Model):
    ...
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, blank = True, null = True,
    related_name = 'comics')
```

Anyway, from this its understandable that 2 comics can share the same topic, however, each comic can only have one topic. Now I need a list of objects of the Topic model ordered according to the number of Comic objects associated with them. For example, say I have a Topic called Unsorted which is associated with 15 comics and another Topic called Funny with 5 comics. I want my query set to be ordered in a way that the Unsorted comes before the Funny object.

```
Topic.objects.all().order_by('-comics')
```

I tried this but it did not really work, the result wasn't sorted the right way, even though there wasn't an error. So any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Whatis the error you get?

Comment: @Gocht: Well there wasn't an error, the result set was just different from what I wanted, that is, it wasn't sorted properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

# ...    

Topic.objects.annotate(cc=Count('comic')).order_by('-cc')
```

Comment: I think you want `'-cc'` for descending order.

Comment: It says there is a NameError: name 'Count' is not defined, is there a library I need to import before using the function? EDIT: never mind, I got it, its from django.db.models