# In Django, how could you serialize the count of ForeignKeys a model instance has?

Tags: django, serialization

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()


class Place(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   city = models.ForeignKey()
```

Say an instance of a city has 50 places. What would be the simplest approach to serializing those city objects and including the place count as property in the serialization

```
json = serialize('json', City.objects.all())
```

I've tried multiple things but they all start getting really messy at one point or another and I've yet to get one to work

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575574/how-to-order-a-queryset-by-related-objects-count/33575751#33575751). Just do the same thing but without the `order_by` and you will have the counts included.

Comment: @Ivan This works to the degree of adding the annotation to each object as a value. However it appears that the django serialization does not support the serialization of these annotations. Thank you though!